# Как получить SearchView из Toolbar Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, android-toolbar, android-search-view

В чем проблема: У меня есть 3 фрагмента, и в каждом из них есть поиск, но я подумал, что лучше будет создать это SearchView в menu toolbar, я доставал его во фрагменте, но почему-то слушатель OnQueryTextListener не работает. А если создать именно внутри фрагмента SearchView то слушатель работает и запрос идет.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title=""
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

Toolbar Menu

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu)
    val search = menu.findItem(R.id.search)
    val searchView: SearchView = search.actionView as SearchView

    searchView.isIconifiedByDefault = false
    searchView.isIconified = false

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            getCharactersByName(query)
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {
            getCharactersByName(query)
            return false
        }
    })
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}

private fun getCharactersByName(query: String?) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.getCharacters(query!!)
    }
}
```

Comment: То что вы привели в коде, это "работает" или "не работает"?

Comment: Это не работает, я ввожу туда текст, а запрос getCharactersByName() не идет